# Dojo not getting loaded into rhino emmbedded in java

Tags: java, dojo, rhino

I'm trying to render the dojo charts server side. I came across the Rhino and envjs for server side browser emulation. when I tried to an example program to load the dojo.js in the rhino embedded in the java impl, the exception is thrown,

> > Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "location" is not defined. (#15) in  at line number 15.

My code is as follows:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Java6RhinoRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    new Java6RhinoRunner().load(args[0]);
  }

  private final ScriptEngine engine;

  public Java6RhinoRunner() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    this.engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    this.engine.put("Java6RhinoRunner", this);
    this.engine.eval("function load(filename) { Java6RhinoRunner.load(filename); }");
  }

  public void load(String filename) throws ScriptException {
    try {
      this.engine.eval(new FileReader(filename));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error loading javascript file: " + filename, e);
    }
  }
}
```

Lots of googling has been done but all in vain.
Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fails because of the way Dojo detects that it is running in the Rhino environment.

The Dojo code was written for compatibility with Rhino's shell (`org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main`) and detects Rhino by looking for features defined by `org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global`. If these are not present Dojo assumes it is running in a browser environment.

It is probably possible to emulate these features by defining them in your script engine but I haven't tried it.

*I wrote [a blog post on running Dojo in embedded Rhino](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/dojo-bootstrapping-in-embedded-rhino.html) but it doesn't use the `ScriptEngine` API.*

Comment: can you give some example. Im relatively new to these things

Comment: You already have an example by defining the global scope `load` function. You will need to add the other features from `Global` that Dojo depends on. You'll need to read the Dojo and/or Rhino source code to determine what those features are. For example, Dojo 1.7.2 detects Rhino with the code `has.add("host-rhino", typeof load == "function" && (typeof Packages == "function" || typeof Packages == "object"));`