# readFully not defined with Java Nashorn Javascript Engine

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I am trying to run a javascript script with the new Java 8 Nashorn javascript engine but it fails with the following error:

```
<eval>:1 ReferenceError: "readFully" is not defined
```

The script uses the readFully function that should be defined in the global scope nashorn is run with the scripting mode enabled (wich is default when running through a ScriptEngine as seen here http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2013-December/002562.html).

Here is a sample to reproduce the error:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

        scriptEngine.eval("print('Hey!');print(print);print(readFully);");


    }
}
```

This sample prints Hey ! and then the source code of the print function (another nashorn built-in function) and finally it should print the source code of the readFully method. But I have this Exception instead:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "readFully" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:586)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:570)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:525)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:521)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:192)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at com.github.bringking.maven.requirejs.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: <eval>:1 ReferenceError: "readFully" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:58)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:320)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:292)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.__noSuchProperty__(NashornScriptEngine.java:272)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$engine.L:35(nashorn:engine/resources/engine.js:37)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.runScript(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:535)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:209)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:568)
    ... 5 more
```

When the sample script is run with the nashorn command line with the -scripting parameter (with the jjs tool of the jdk), all is fine. Here is the result of the same script:

```
Hey!
function print() { [native code] }
function readFully() { [native code] }
```

I could rewrite a readFully method and bind it with the script context, but I prefer to understand why it does not work and use already built-in functions.

Regards

Comment: What JDK are you using? Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: Orcale JDK on Windows 7: java version "1.8.0_25", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18), Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: The blog post you linked to is re: openjdk. They're still a bit different.

Comment: Indeed. 1 point. So, now I am looking for a way to programmatically "force" the scripting mode of Nashorn :)

Comment: Not sure. But your engine should probable be `javascript` (not `nashorn`) --- what if they rename it in Java 9?

Comment: I have tried with javascript with the same result. I have used nashorn in this sample to be sure that nashorn is used (even if it is the only one available by default). I will try to run this sample with an OpenJDK 8.

Comment: Tried with openjdk 1.8.0_u45-ea and does not work.

Comment: You can pass options to Nashorn using the direct nashorn interface or simply put a '#' as the first character of the script.

Comment: NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
String[] options = new String[] { "—scripting" };
NashornScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(options);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have implemented a readFully function that I use in my script (Only compatible with Nashorn):

```
function readFully(url) {
    var result = "";
    var imports = new JavaImporter(java.net, java.lang, java.io);

    with (imports) {

        var urlObj = null;

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);
        } catch (e) {
            // If the URL cannot be built, assume it is a file path.
            urlObj = new URL(new File(url).toURI().toURL());
        }

        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlObj.openStream()));

        var line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            result += line + "\n";
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*readFully* is not a standard JavaScript function and it is likely not standard in Nashorn either.

There were [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969392) when Rhino was chosen for inclusion in the Sun implementation of Java 6. The scripting tool may provide enhancements that are not present in the embedded API. *readFully* is not a documented function in the [Java 8 Nashorn API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html).

In previous versions of Java the specification stated that provided scripting engines were an implementation detail of the JRE vendor. I am not aware if Java 8 makes anything about the engines provided mandatory or whether it makes any future compatibility guarantees. I would check [JSR-337](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337) thoroughly if this was likely to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will implement a readFully function by myself.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions

readFully (-scripting mode only)

This function reads the entire contents of a file passed in as a string argument and sends it to stdout, or you can assign the result to a variable.

readFully example:

`jjs> readFully("text.txt")
This is the contents of the text.txt file located in the current working directory.`

Comment: My problem is that readFully is not defined when running through the ScriptEngine API. Not with the jjs executable (this way, all is fine).

Comment: You can pass options to Nashorn using the direct nashorn interface

NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
String[] options = new String[] { "—scripting" };
NashornScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(options);

or simply put a '#' as the first character of the script.

Comment: You can actually set/reset the option through a system property programmatically with `System.setProperty("nashorn.args", "-scripting")` which will give you the best of both worlds: you can stick to the `javax.script` API and you can still control the option per engine". Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873201/enable-scripting-mode-for-nashorn-in-java

Answer (score 0):

readFully is enabled only in scripting mode. [Nashorn docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/shell.html#JSNUG144)

try this:

```
>>jjs -scripting
jjs> readFully("your_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

readFully() function is only available as built in function in nashorgn when you enable scripting in you application
There are two ways you can do this:-

1. pass `-Dnashorn.args=-scripting` when you run your application to enable nashorn 
   scripting
2. Enable it programmatically by creating Nashorn engine with scripting args

   ```
   NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
   ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(new String[] { "-scripting" });
   ```