# Running jsdom in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, playframework, nashorn

I want to render d3 charts on the server.  I had 3 options:  Node, Phantom, and Nashorn.

I prefer Nashorn because my API is Scala Play and I don't want to manage another process.  (deployment, load, queue, etc etc)

So now I need to get JSDom working in Nashorn, so that D3 will have something to render to.

This works so far but I can't figure out how to add jsdom

```
class Application @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends api.ApiController {

  def test = ApiAction { implicit request =>
    ok("The API is ready")
  }

  def pptx = Action { implicit request =>
    val manager: ScriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager
    val engine: ScriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn")
    engine.eval(new FileReader(Play.getFile("/ext/lodash.js")))
    val output = engine.eval("function hello(){return _.join('Hello world nashorn does this thing'.split(' '), '-');} hello();")
    Ok(output.toString)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What problems you have encountered? jsdom has a lot of dependencies and those probably have deps also, so you may need to add all those manually. I'm not sure about it, but a tool like browserify or webpack may help here (convert a module to basically a single js)...

Comment: well - obtaining jsdom.js in the first place.  there's no download link.

Comment: I found a fourth option, typesafehub/webdriver uses rhino and htmlunit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm loading a fork of [domino](https://github.com/jazdw/domino) in nashorn to run d3. Domino is a server-side DOM implementation based on Mozilla's dom.js. I loaded it using r.js from require.js. You can use [this readfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788356/readfully-not-defined-with-java-nashorn-javascript-engine#27788879) function that is missing from nashorn to get require.js working.

Comment: Hey @EricHartford, can you share your final solution? how did you end up "requiring" domino?

Comment: I used webpack or browserify to pack my dependencies, then I loaded the output into nashorn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use headless browser selenium Chrome driver.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Program-Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        try {
           // String html_content = "<html><head></head><body><div>Hello World</div></body></html>";
            //driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html_content);
            driver.get("D:\\Projects\\Selenium1\\inputfile.html");
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String html1 = (String) js.executeScript("return document.head.innerHTML;");
            System.out.println(html1);
            String html = (String) js.executeScript("return document.body.innerHTML;");
            System.out.println(html);
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good example of extreme coupling.