# Drawing to an HTML5 canvas and saving *within* a Scala app

Tags: javascript, scala, html5-canvas

I'm looking for a way on my Scala backend to draw to an HTML5 canvas based on some events, and perodically snapshot the state of the canvas and save it as an image that the scala runtime can access.

I looked into the Rhino scripting engine, but that doesn't seem to support an HTML5 canvas. I also looked into Scala.js, but that seems a way to just generate client code-- and I couldn't get it within the [same module](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1590) as my play server.

Any recomendations? I'm looking to have this run within scala as to not require interprocess communication-- this is just for a fun/personal project, so I'm curious to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a requirement that your "Scala runtime" is on the JVM (otherwise consider Node.js with jsdom)? Also, would a Java graphics object (from swing for example) do as well or does it have to be an HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425346/running-jsdom-in-nashorn It may be possible to use domino DOM implementation in Nashorn, or simulate a browser within JVM with typesafehub/webdriver. Similarly, you may be able to apply Rhino with a DOM library like domino.

Comment: Great find, @Kolmar! That looks like just the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: So I ended up doing a fair amount research into this-- I tried loading jsdom into nashorn, but the HTML5 canvas is just mocked out in jsdom. 

I think the best way to do this probably would be to run a really basic PhantomJS server that my main server communicated with-- but that's not really the kind of solution I was looking for, so I may or may not end up going with it.